How do I add line breaks in netcat server mode?
I am using netcat server mode.
The client sends "Hello World!! 232733".
There is no line feed code at the end.
It will be displayed as below.
$ nc -lp 8080
Hello World!! 252733Hello World!! 252833Hello World!! 252933Hello World!! 253033

Is it possible to display it as below?
Hello World!! 252733
Hello World!! 252833
Hello World!! 252933
Hello World!! 253033

